# Dictionary passed to js not working

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to javascript. I am working on django project. I need to pass the dictionary template variable to javascript and I have not been able.

views.py includes:

```
def index(request):
   name={'bishal':509,'bishnu':510}
   return render_to_response("test.html",Context({'name':simplejson.dumps(name)}))
```

test.html includes:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block include_js %}
<script src="{% static "js/chart.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/test.js" %}"> </script>
{% endblock include_js %}

{% block main_content %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var name={{name}};
    </script>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" type="button" onclick="myfunction()">1st visualization</button>
    {% endblock %}
```

test.js includes:

```
$(function myfunction() {
 document.getElementById('btn1').onclick=function(){
        name=JSON.parse(name);
        alert(name);
   };
});
```

But error occurs saying:

```
[30/Jul/2013 02:50:51] "GET /visualize/static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2732
```

I tried similar thing in html as:

```
    <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction()
{
    dict=JSON.parse(dict);
    alert(dict);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var dict='{"bishnu": 509, "bishal": 510}';
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" 
onclick="myfunction()" 
value="Call function">
</form>

<p>By pressing the button, a function will be called. The function will alert a message.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

which worked perfectly. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Ignore all the JavaScript. The key line in your problem is:

```
[30/Jul/2013 02:50:51] "GET /visualize/static/js/test.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2732
```

404 is the HTTP code for 'file not found', which means that you're using the incorrect path to reference your JavaScript file. Fix that, and you may find that your solution then works - or, if not, at least breaks differently.

Comment: I would like to add to OP that what you're doing is considered very bad practice and should be avoided as much as possible!

Comment: @limelights If you want to add that as a separate answer with suggestions for improvement, I'd be happy to upvote in order that the original questioner at least sees it. I suspect though that he's maintaining someone else's code, and may not be in a position to change it himself.

Comment: path is correct because it works for strings passed similarly

Comment: Let's assume then that it's more complex than it seems, and chart.js and test.js are both in this same folder. Can you demonstrate that the chart.js that loads is definitely the one from that location (e.g. put an `alert()` at the top of it)? Also, is there any chance you've mistyped the filename somewhere, or there's a space in the filename that you've missed?

Comment: @limelights Could you expand on what is the bad practice here?

Answer (score 0):

@Adrian is right about the error message, but I suspect that the problem you're thinking of is caused by not putting quotes around `{{name}}` in test.html. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name='{{name}}';
</script>
```